# SQL Queries with the Table function

Tags: sql

Given the following connection to an SQL query works but the data comes out wrong:

```
data = Table[SQLSelect[conn, "All", {"col1", "col2"}, 
   SQLColumn["col1"] == n && SQLColumn["col2"] ==  o], {n, 1, 8}, {o, 21,
    30}];
```

If I do not use the 'Table' function, I get the expected results by inserting the actual numbers after == when running the query. I need to create a 54 x 289 table from my data and obviously for this large data set this will be impractical to key in and export piece by piece.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this `data = SQLSelect[conn, "All", {"col1", "col2"}, SQLMemberQ[Range@8, SQLColumn["col1"]] && SQLMemberQ[Range[21, 30], SQLColumn["col2"]]];`

Comment: I can't test it, will post as an answer if it works

Comment: Much better! I had to increase the Java heap size for jDBC (I went from 3GB to 4GB). It executed many many times faster . I think I still have a logic problem telling the query which rows to select but this is a step in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: When you come to solve it, post it as an answer and ping me to upvote

Comment: I think we can offer your post as an answer. It does do what I asked. I just need to refine my question for the results I was desiring. I upvoted your suggestion. Where did that confounded mark as answer button go?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data = SQLSelect[conn, "All", {"col1", "col2"}, 
                 SQLMemberQ[Range@8, SQLColumn["col1"]] && 
                 SQLMemberQ[Range[21, 30], SQLColumn["col2"]]];
```